# How to change Test Movie window size in Flash CS 5/6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I've been working with stage of size 1152x1536 and when I test the movie it appears in full resolution. Is there any way I can change Test Movie window size in Flash CS 5/6? Thanks.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to do, is it to set the size of the swf that is launched (stage-size of swf)? Is it the movieclip attached to the stage that you want another size of?

Comment: @DanielMesSer Thanks for the reply, sorry for being a bit vague (I'm new to this). Yes I believe it's the swf stage-size I want to change, content resolution will be the same though. This is just for ease of viewing purpose only. Basically, I wanna see high res stage content in a smaller window (1/4 the stage res maybe) but when I actually publish the project it will have the original resolution (1152x1536).

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the root/stage of your FLA-file and click on the movie clip, set the size of it by changing the properties of the movie clip.

If you want to change the size of the stage, go to root, then click on nothing, that way you get another option in property window where you can set stage size (also available from publish settings).

If you only want to resize the SWF you have to launch it and then resize the window. It's also possible to do when launching through html and allow scale and set size as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To create a keyframe, select Insert > Timeline > Keyframe (F6), or right-click (Windows) or Control‑click (Macintosh) the frame where you want to place a keyframe, and select Insert Keyframe from the context menu.